# Get the output of the time command

Tags: bash, time, output

I have the following command

```
time compare -metric rmse -subimage-search -dissimilarity-threshold 1 -similarity-threshold 0.99 $page \( -size 1x1 xc:black \) null:
```

which produces the following results:

```
0 (0) @ 7,0
real    0m28.366s
user    0m25.400s
sys     0m1.500s
```

I'm looking to store the results of the command in an array, as such

```
declare -a Pageinfo=($(time compare -metric rmse -subimage-search -dissimilarity-threshold 1 -similarity-threshold 0.99 out1.tif \( -size 1x1 xc:black \) null: ))

echo "Pageinfo results  =  ${Pageinfo[*]}"
```

however, array is empty. Why?

Comment: @mikeserv won't work. You need a subshell and you must redirect the stderr of the subshell. `time` is really annoying that way.

Comment: It's not clear what your trying to achieve: what do you want to store in the array? the result of `compare` or the result of `time`? (or both?). Because as you wrote your command, `Pageinfo` contains what `compare` outputs on standard output.

Comment: acually, want both results, that of the compare and time command in the array.

Comment: Please. clarify exactly what you want. Saying _actually, want both results_ doesn't tell us _how_ you want them. If you want the result of `time` in an array `myTime` and the result of the command in an array `Pageinfo`, please _make that very, very clear in your question_. (No offense, but you're not enough _clear_ and _precise_ in your question).

Comment: Forgive me I was not clear enough, and no offense taken.  I would like to store the results in one array, starting with the results of the convert command,  follow be the results of time. so ideally, the array should have contain the following. --  0 (0) @ 7,0 real    0m28.366s   user    0m25.400s    sys     0m1.500s --  I have been trying to do so, but not there yet. and thank you the guidance. To see the acutall example will benefit greatly!

Comment: Actually - i think a got it. --- I tried for like a hour before. seems i need to take a step back. I never included a SPACE around the Curly brackets which caused the command to fail!

Answer (score 2):

The `time` command will print its output to standard error, not standard output. So that's what you need to capture. Then, you need to capture the output of `time` and not the output of the command you are timing. Typically, this is done by grouping or running the commands in a subshell (in `{ }` or `( )` respecitvely), redirecting  the group's output to `/dev/null` and redirecting its error to standard output. For example:

```
$ declare -a array=( $( { time ls; } 2>&1 >/dev/null ))
$ echo ${array[*]} 
real 0m0.003s user 0m0.000s sys 0m0.000s
```

To save each *line* as an array element, use the `mapfile` builtin. However, the array created will only be available within the grouping:

```
$ { time ls; } 2>&1 >/dev/null | { 
    mapfile  array1; 
    echo "1:     ${array1[1]}2:${array1[2]}3:${array1[3]}"; 
  } 
1: real 0m0.003s
2:user  0m0.000s
3:sys   0m0.000s
```

I'm not sure if you want the output of the command in the array or only the output of `time`. If you want the command as well, remove the `> /dev/null` from each of the examples above.

Comment: Now if you also need to have the output of the command on the terminal, you'll need to do some plumbing `;)`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf true, grouping also works. I'd used it for the `mapfile` approach but used the subshell for the other out of habit. Answer edited.

Comment: @mikeserv you mean time? It's either a shell keyword or a separate binary at `/usr/bin/time`. I used _command_ as a generic term.

Comment: True - I completely forgot about the separate executable. But about `times` I meant `times`.

Comment: @user68650 If this answer solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Comment: Hi terdon. From the OP's comment, it seems the answer is: `mapfile -t Pageinfo < <( { time ls 2>/dev/null; } 2>&1 )` (with `ls` replaced by `compare ...`).